# Need help with a solution for current measuring

Tags: current, sensor, current-measurement

I need a solution for measuring current through a load. It is a 15W load at 230 VAC or 24 VDC. I found the TMCS1100A4 from TI ([datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tmcs1100.pdf?HQS=TI-null-null-alldatasheets-df-pf-SEP-wwe&ts=1614173907230&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.alldatasheet.com%252Fdatasheet-pdf%252Fpdf%252F1230339%252FTI1%252FTMCS1100.html)). It's very nice because it can measure both AC and DC easily and the input and output are isolated. The downside is the sensitivity at 400 mV/A is probably a bit to low, as it would result in an output of 26 mV (at 230V input).
Does anyone have some suggetions for other sensors or ways of measuring the current?

I do not need to know the exact current, the output of the sensor will go to some comparators to detect if there is a current and if the current is too high (to indicate a short circuit for example).

Comment: I'm not sure a Hall effect sensor is appropriate for this, if you expect such low currents. Try using the Hall effect sensor for DC measurements, and a current transformer (possibly with multiple windings) for AC ones?

Comment: Compared to other current measurement techniques 26mV is lots (I work with current measurement where the output is 1000 times less)  just design your amplifier electroincs carefully and think about sources of error such as magnetic coupling.

Comment: @JasonMorgan Wouldn't I have a lot of issue with noise? I could imagine the noise from EMI would (sometimes) exceed 26mV, or be enough to trigger a false positive. Not really relevant to my question but: how do you handle the output in your applications, where the signal is so small? Just lots of filtering and really precise amplifiers?

Comment: https://www.allegromicro.com/en/products/sense/current-sensor-ics/zero-to-fifty-amp-integrated-conductor-sensor-ics

Comment: A well designed circuit can easily cope with amplifying mV signals.  Use differential signals.  Keep traces short, Use anti-magnetic loop area ballancing.